# Pass ASP as PHP on nginx

Tags: nginx, php, mime, extension

I have been trying to parse .ASP files as PHP, but no matter what I try (for hours), it just doesn't work. None of the tutorials/notes I find seem to work for me!
Either file(s) get downloaded with their PHP code not being processed, or I get a ridiculous and stupid "Access denied." error (single line, by the way; so I can't say if is it fault from PHP parser or nginx)

I have tried this setup:

```
# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.asp$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.asp)(/.+)$;
#   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
#
#   # With php5-cgi alone:
#   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#   # With php5-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.asp;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

What's wrong? :S

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed: From /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf, I added the .asp extension to security.limit_extensions. That made the trick.